# How to execute remote mysql query after granting permission?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, query

I am trying to execute mysql query from another ubuntu system.

I have granted permission to user using GRANT from 192.168.64.9

GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'user'@'192.168.64.11' WITH GRANT OPTION;

and then on 192.168.64.11

sudo mysql -u user -p 'password' -h 192.168.64.9

ERROR 10045 ACCESS DENIED FOR user@192.168.64.11

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in your grant statement that attempted to grant all on **`.`**, which is not valid.

**Instead, do the following:**

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'192.168.64.11' IDENTIFIED BY 'theuserpasswordgoeshere';
```

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'192.168.64.11' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**Then:**

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now you should be able to query remotely from the client at 192.168.64.11